# Simple Voice Recognition Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, voice-recognition, voice

In my app when the user says a certain word or words the app will answer by  reading out a sentence which is set in app. What is the simplest way of doing this?

I'm using the latest version of Xcode
(Its for my WWDC 2015 scholarship app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use

OpenEars SDK
http://www.politepix.com/openears/

or

AT&T Watson
http://developer.att.com/apis/speech

Answer (score 9):

As of iOS 10 you can use [Speech.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017084-DontLinkElementID_3):

```
import Speech

let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: audioFileURL)
recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
     print (result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)
})
```

Comment: what is this audioFileURL

Comment: The URL of the audio file you want to be recognized. You can also use an audio buffer if you want real time recognition

Comment: But Speech framework has limitation of one minute recording. And how to achieve for long audio file. Like recording from time to time in the audio file.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use `SpeechKit`. Ray has a nice tutorial here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/60870/building-ios-app-like-siri

The SDK is developed by Nuance (the dragon people):

http://nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php

Comment: My app is coded in Swift, a lot of people including me had a lot of trouble trying to get speechKit to work on swift. Would you perhaps know any other tutorials in swift? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Junaid You can always use Objective-C and Swift together in the same application. Simply write the parts interfacing with `SpeechKit` in Objective-C then interface with that using a bridging header. I don't know of any other good tutorials that I'd recommend but I'll keep looking

Comment: I´m struggling to make my Swift app use Speechkit. Initializing works fine but I cant figure out how to implement override callback methods from SpeechKit (didFinishWithErrors, didFinishWithResults, etc) into the .swift code. Just adding those methods to a protocol won´t do, you can add methods there, but it does not make any sense.

Comment: Well I have used SpeechKit in my Swift app working perfectly.

Comment: @Vakas can you please post your Swift based implementation (either here or in a new new SO post, please?)

Comment: @Sean there is a simple example [here](https://github.com/tanmayb123/NuanceSpeechKit_Swift) that works in Swift 2.